# sql error- "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE"

Tags: sql

```
SELECT ship from Outcomes outer
WHERE EXIST(select ship from Outcomes inner
where inner.ship=outer.ship
)
```

Why am I receiving error

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE"

Comment: Outer and inner are both reserved words. Use something else! (Or double quote them, e.g. "outer".) Also, its EXISTS, not EXIST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use keywords for alias names as `outer` and `inner` which just start confusion. Also it is `exists`.

```
SELECT ship from Outcomes o
WHERE EXISTS
(
  select ship from Outcomes i
  where i.ship = o.ship
)
```

Your query also does not make much sense. You are comparing a all column values of a table with itself. The result should output all `ship` and you could just do

```
SELECT ship from Outcomes
```

instead.

Comment: What's the meaning of this query?

Comment: The alternative is "SELECT ship from Outcomes WHERE ship IS NOT NULL"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ship from Outcomes o1
WHERE EXISTS(select ship from Outcomes o2
             where o2.ship = o1.ship)
```

Outer and inner are both reserved words. Use something else! (Or double quote them, e.g. `"outer"`.) Also, it's `EXISTS`, not EXIST.

Answer (score -1):

outer and inner are reserved keywords. You can better use other aliases or put the names between square brackets []

```
SELECT ship from Outcomes otr
WHERE EXIST(select ship from Outcomes inr
where inr.ship=otr.ship
)
```

or

```
SELECT ship from Outcomes [outer]
WHERE EXIST(select ship from Outcomes [inner]
where [inner].ship=[outer].ship
)
```

The squery bracktes only work if you are using SQL server

Comment: just as jarlh suggested, instead of suggesting `[]` suggest the use of `"`